# How to load another page file of my custom plugin file

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

I'm creating my own plugin for medical purpose. in the site front end using shortcode i created a login form. so after logged in the doctor can see list of patients with and edit link to each row. i did the same in wp-admin plugin backend functionality which is did using add_submenu. but i need to provide the same in front end also.

**My Issue:**

on clicking the edit link i have to load another form with filled conetent from db. but when i give header(location: ...) it shows **header already sent error**. Code is too long so i'm giving the structure of the code that working till now.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])|| isset($_POST['Save'])){
   <form id="patientadd"...>
   Form for adding new patients. this must be visible only after logged in
   <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Add"/>
   </form>

   <table id="pat_list">
   Table Listing out the patients id,email,mobile,name 
   <a href="">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=""> Delete</a>
   </table>

 }

 else{ ?>php
 <form id="loginform" ...>
  Login form with username and password
  <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login"/>
  </form>
 <?php } ?>
```

So these are all written in one file "patient_reg.php". When `edit` link is clicked another form with that patient's details must be displayed. i'm confused about how i should attain this.

What i tried to solve this issue is:

Onclicking the edit link i call a javascript function "showedit()" which do:

```
function showedit(){
document.patientadd.style.display="none";
   }
```

But this gives me the login form.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @Mr.Happy : hi... I have updated my question with code

Comment: So your trying to load another form on edit anchor. Am I right?

Comment: yeah.. thats the only way i thought because the redirection to another file is not working.. if u have any other better idea than this please tell me..

Comment: You can use Ajax to load another form.